# Hook working for notepad.exe but not for cmd.exe

Tags: vb.net, cmd, hook, parent-child, setparent

I'm using the code down below to start cmd.exe and move it into my panel. The problem is that my form does not switch to the foreground when I click on the embedded cmd window. It does work when I change `Process.Start` to notepad.exe. Does anybody know why it's not working for cmd?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards,
Eric van Loon

**Form1.vb:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports WindowsApp1.NativeMethods
Public Class Form1
    Private hForegroundChangedEventHook As IntPtr
    Private ReadOnly ForegroundChangedEventDelegate As WinEventDelegate
    Private Shared GCForegroundStateSafetyHandle As GCHandle
    Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim proc As Process
        Dim ProcId As Integer = 0
        'proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
        proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe")
        proc.WaitForExit(200)
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Me.Panel1.Handle)
        SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0)
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(proc.MainWindowHandle, ProcId)
        SetForegroundStateChangedHook(proc.MainWindowHandle)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ForegroundChangedEventDelegate = New WinEventDelegate(AddressOf ForegroundStateChangedCallback)
        GCForegroundStateSafetyHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ForegroundChangedEventDelegate)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleDestroyed(e As EventArgs)
        GCForegroundStateSafetyHandle.Free()
        UnhookWinEvent(hForegroundChangedEventHook)
        MyBase.OnHandleDestroyed(e)
    End Sub
    Private Sub SetForegroundStateChangedHook(hWnd As IntPtr)
        Dim processId As UInteger
        Dim targetThreadId = GetWindowThread(hWnd, processId)
        hForegroundChangedEventHook = WinEventHookOne(SWEH_Events.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, ForegroundChangedEventDelegate, processId, targetThreadId)
    End Sub
    Friend Sub ForegroundStateChangedCallback(hWinEventHook As IntPtr, eventType As SWEH_Events, hWnd As IntPtr, idObject As SWEH_ObjectId, idChild As Long, dwEventThread As UInteger, dwmsEventTime As UInteger)
        If idObject = SWEH_ObjectId.OBJID_WINDOW AndAlso eventType = SWEH_Events.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND Then
            Dim flags = SWP_Flags.SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS Or SWP_Flags.SWP_NOACTIVATE Or SWP_Flags.SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_Flags.SWP_NOMOVE
            SetWindowPos(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Class1.vb:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class NativeMethods

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Friend Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As UInteger) As UInteger
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Friend Shared Function SetWindowPos(hWnd As IntPtr, hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, x As Integer, y As Integer, cx As Integer, cy As Integer, uFlags As SWP_Flags) As Boolean
    End Function

    Friend Delegate Sub WinEventDelegate(
        hWinEventHook As IntPtr,
        eventType As SWEH_Events,
        hwnd As IntPtr, idObject As SWEH_ObjectId,
        idChild As Long,
        dwEventThread As UInteger,
        dwmsEventTime As UInteger)

    Friend Shared Function WinEventHookOne(evt As SWEH_Events, weDelegate As WinEventDelegate, idProcess As UInteger, idThread As UInteger) As IntPtr
        Return SetWinEventHook(evt, evt, IntPtr.Zero, weDelegate, idProcess, idThread, WinEventHookInternalFlags)
    End Function


    Friend Shared Function GetWindowThread(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef processID As UInteger) As UInteger
        processID = 0
        Return GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, processID)
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=False)>
    Friend Shared Function SetWinEventHook(
        eventMin As SWEH_Events,
        eventMax As SWEH_Events,
        hmodWinEventProc As IntPtr,
        lpfnWinEventProc As WinEventDelegate,
        idProcess As UInteger,
        idThread As UInteger,
        dwFlags As SWEH_dwFlags) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=False)>
    Friend Shared Function UnhookWinEvent(hWinEventHook As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    Friend Shared WinEventHookInternalFlags As SWEH_dwFlags =
        SWEH_dwFlags.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT Or SWEH_dwFlags.WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS


    ' SetWinEventHook Events
    Friend Enum SWEH_Events As UInteger
        EVENT_MIN = &H1
        EVENT_MAX = &H7FFFFFFF
        EVENT_SYSTEM_SOUND = &H1
        EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT = &H2
        EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = &H3
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART = &H4
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND = &H5
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART = &H6
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND = &H7
        EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART = &H8
        EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND = &H9
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART = &HA
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND = &HB
        EVENT_SYSTEM_CONTEXTHELPSTART = &HC
        EVENT_SYSTEM_CONTEXTHELPEND = &HD
        EVENT_SYSTEM_DRAGDROPSTART = &HE
        EVENT_SYSTEM_DRAGDROPEND = &HF
        EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART = &H10
        EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGEND = &H11
        EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGSTART = &H12
        EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGEND = &H13
        EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART = &H14
        EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND = &H15
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART = &H16
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND = &H17
        EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH = &H20
        EVENT_SYSTEM_END = &HFF
        EVENT_OEM_DEFINED_START = &H101
        EVENT_OEM_DEFINED_END = &H1FF
        EVENT_UIA_EVENTID_START = &H4E00
        EVENT_UIA_EVENTID_END = &H4EFF
        EVENT_UIA_PROPID_START = &H7500
        EVENT_UIA_PROPID_END = &H75FF
        EVENT_CONSOLE_CARET = &H4001
        EVENT_CONSOLE_UPDATE_REGION = &H4002
        EVENT_CONSOLE_UPDATE_SIMPLE = &H4003
        EVENT_CONSOLE_UPDATE_SCROLL = &H4004
        EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT = &H4005
        EVENT_CONSOLE_START_APPLICATION = &H4006
        EVENT_CONSOLE_END_APPLICATION = &H4007
        EVENT_CONSOLE_END = &H40FF
        EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE = &H8000
        EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY = &H8001
        EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW = &H8002
        EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE = &H8003
        EVENT_OBJECT_REORDER = &H8004
        EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS = &H8005
        EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION = &H8006
        EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTIONADD = &H8007
        EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTIONREMOVE = &H8008
        EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTIONWITHIN = &H8009
        EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE = &H800A
        EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE = &H800B
        EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE = &H800C
        EVENT_OBJECT_DESCRIPTIONCHANGE = &H800D
        EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE = &H800E
        EVENT_OBJECT_PARENTCHANGE = &H800F
        EVENT_OBJECT_HELPCHANGE = &H8010
        EVENT_OBJECT_DEFACTIONCHANGE = &H8011
        EVENT_OBJECT_ACCELERATORCHANGE = &H8012
        EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED = &H8013
        EVENT_OBJECT_TEXTSELECTIONCHANGED = &H8014
        EVENT_OBJECT_CONTENTSCROLLED = &H8015
        EVENT_SYSTEM_ARRANGMENTPREVIEW = &H8016
        EVENT_OBJECT_END = &H80FF
        EVENT_AIA_START = &HA000
        EVENT_AIA_END = &HAFFF
    End Enum

    ' SetWinEventHook Window Objects
    Friend Enum SWEH_ObjectId As Long
        OBJID_WINDOW = &H0
        OBJID_SYSMENU = &HFFFFFFFFUI
        OBJID_TITLEBAR = &HFFFFFFFEUI
        OBJID_MENU = &HFFFFFFFDUI
        OBJID_CLIENT = &HFFFFFFFCUI
        OBJID_VSCROLL = &HFFFFFFFBUI
        OBJID_HSCROLL = &HFFFFFFFAUI
        OBJID_SIZEGRIP = &HFFFFFFF9UI
        OBJID_CARET = &HFFFFFFF8UI
        OBJID_CURSOR = &HFFFFFFF7UI
        OBJID_ALERT = &HFFFFFFF6UI
        OBJID_SOUND = &HFFFFFFF5UI
        OBJID_QUERYCLASSNAMEIDX = &HFFFFFFF4UI
        OBJID_NATIVEOM = &HFFFFFFF0UI
    End Enum

    ' WinEventDelegate flags
    Friend Enum SWEH_dwFlags As UInteger
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = &H0     ' Events are ASYNC - No dll needed
        WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD = &H1    ' Don't call back for events on installer's thread
        WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS = &H2   ' Don't call back for events on installer's process
        WINEVENT_INCONTEXT = &H4        ' Events are SYNC, this causes your dll to be injected into every process
    End Enum

    ' SetWindowPos flags
    <Flags>
    Public Enum SWP_Flags As UInteger
        SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
        SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
        SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
        SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
        SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
        SWP_DRAWFRAME = &H20
        SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
        SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
        SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
        SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200
        SWP_NOREPOSITION = &H200
        SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = &H400
        SWP_NOCLIENTSIZE = &H800
        SWP_NOCLIENTMOVE = &H1000
        SWP_DEFERERASE = &H2000
        SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = &H4000
    End Enum
End Class
```

Comment: The Console Window doesn't belong to the CMD Process (or Thread), so you don't get any notification when you interact with it (and hooking conhost.exe is probably not what you want) -- It's probably easier to override WndProc and handle [WM_ACTIVATEAPP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-activateapp) in this case -- You could switch from one mode to the other when `proc.WaitForInputIdle()` fails

Comment: Hi (again) @Jimi I'm not a very skilled VB coder. Without asking you to completely writing the code, can you please give me some hints how to do this or where to find an example?

Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.
Kind regards,
Eric

Comment: The idea would be that, when you first host that Window, you bring it to front, which causes the hosting Form to be deactivated. The Form receives a `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message, with `WParam` set to `false` and `LParam` referencing the owner Thread that's being activated instead. You store this value the first time you receive the message (you know you have caused it). The next time, compare `LParam` with this value (now not `0`); if it matches, then the Windows that's being activated is the hosted Console Window, so you call `SetWindowPos()` -- Note that this all is really unsupported

Comment: Hi @Jimi I spend a whole day Googling for answers, but can't find any usable examples. I lack the knowledge to turn your suggestions into code myself...
I think I have to create something like:
`Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
 If ... then
  do something
else
  do something
End Sub`
But I don't understand what I need to code in the if-then-else and how I should store the owner thread (which is not proc.MainWindowHandle, right?). I hope you can find some time to help me out again? This is the main, last hurdle in my project.
Thanks again for your time!